# ggplotly tooltip not showing correct text

Tags: r, r-plotly, ggplotly

I made a bar graph with ggplotly. In the tooltip, it always shows text like this  `paste(hp, 'hp') 335 hp`. What I need is just like this format:  `hp: 335 hp`. I have no clue why that happens.  Does anyone knows how to fix that?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
mtcars$cars = row.names(mtcars)
g = mtcars %>%
        arrange(desc(hp)) %>% 
        head(., 10) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x= reorder(cars, hp), y=hp,
                   text=cars, text1 = paste(hp, 'hp') ))+
        geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='darkred')+
        coord_flip()
ggplotly(g,  tooltip = c("text","text1") )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting all text into one line and using a new line break `\n`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
mtcars$cars = row.names(mtcars)
g = mtcars %>%
  arrange(desc(hp)) %>% 
  head(., 10) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= reorder(cars, hp), y=hp,
             text = paste0(cars, "\n", "hp: ", hp) ))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='darkred')+
  coord_flip()
ggplotly(g,  tooltip = c("text","text1") )
```